# Check for hardcoded text in Rails views - I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, view, config, rails-i18n

some of our devs (me included) don't always take it serious to put text in a localization file, result is a lot of hardcoded texts scattered around a lot of views. 
I'm wondering if any of you has an idea to automate the search for hardcoded texts in views? Has anyone a tool or an approach how to check for this? I was thinking if a nifty bash script would do the job, but I'm a bit lost where to start. Any help much appreciated.

Edit: **Not 100% accurate but works best for me so I accepted Andi's answer.**

Comment: Do you know what text you want to search for?

Comment: @SekalfNroc no, just hardcoded text any sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get very far by just using grep:

```
cat $(find . | grep .html.erb) | grep -v '[=<>{}$/;]' | grep '\w \w'
```

This finds texts based on the idea that there are some characters which are not typical for texts

```
grep -v '[=<>{}$/;]'
```

and that there should be at least one space with a preceding word character and one where a word character follows

```
grep '\w \w'
```

This might not be a hundred percent accurate but is a fast and easy way to quickly check for hard coded text.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It found one of the pieces of hard-coded text in my project, but it mostly found Ruby code where there was a space between the method name and the arguments.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend it to find two white spaces per line `grep '\(\w\+\s\)\{2,\}'`. It was just meant as a good starting point which can be optimized. Just change `2` to `4` and see what happens, for example.

Comment: @Andi this is working quite well so far. I need to check more in depth to see if it is reliable!

Comment: @supersize good to hear that i could help. Did you extend some of the `grep` commands? Could you post your final solution so i can edit the answer and add it?

Comment: @Andi a late reply but I was involved in something else until now. I noticed that it would be great that if we could exclude a preceding `if` or `unless` and it would get closer to the desired result. I have a lot of Ruby methods matches but just because of conditions.

Comment: @Andi consider this as the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

If most lines of code are short and the hard-coded text is long, you can use `strings -n [number]` to find any text with a particular number of characters.

```
  <html>                                  |
   <head>                                 |
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                                          |
     <title>Example Page</title>          |
                                          |
   </head>                                |
                                          |
   <body>                                 |
     <h1><%= @page.name %></h1>           |
     <p>                                  |
       This is a piece of hard coded text which must be found.
     </p>                                 |
   </body>                                |
  </html>                                 | 40 characters
```

If you set the length to 40...

```
$ cat $(find . | grep .html.erb) | strings -n 40
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  This is a piece of hard coded text which must be found.
```

It should be mostly accurate in finding hard-coded text.

Comment: neat idea but in reality this spits out loads of long lines which are CSS classes in HAML too

Comment: you could probably use this method + nokogiri and consume the views/partials. But you'd have to skip the preprocessor that erb runs so that you see the erb tags and have something to filter based on, as you'd see the erb tags (<%= %>) as text. You might have to script the duplication of erb files and remove the .erb extension but I would think you could write something fairly quickly to do this operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to find anything neither enclosed within angle brackets (catching most HTML tags and Ruby) nor inside style, script or title tags.

`^(?!.*(<(style|script|title).*?<\/\1>|<.*?>)).*$`

If you discover that any other tags are getting through, just add them to the list of exceptions.

Comment: I notice that someone voted down this answer. Please, could you explain? I'm happy to improve it according to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by Andi's answer but also wanted an easy way to jump straight to the file and line (and to instead search for words that start with a capital letter)

```
grep -r -n ".\+[ >^=]\([A-Z][a-z]\+\b\)" .
```

This command recursively greps all files in a folder and puts the filename and line number in each result, like so:

```
./interviews/show.html.erb:17:              Your interview has been scheduled
./interviews/show.html.erb:49:              Click the button below to add this event to your calendar.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some "extractors" mentioned in the [custom tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/wiki#custom-tasks) page for [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks).

They offer to automatically extract hardcoded text from your Views into your Yaml files, or even the database ([Lost In Translation](https://github.com/prograils/lit)).

Most seem to offer an interactive mode so you could use them just to identify hardcoded text, even if you don't want to auto-extract it.

I have tried any of them so can't comment on their effectiveness.

Answer (score -2):

why don't you raise exception in development and test environments when the translations are missing. In development and test environments you can add this:

```
Rails.application.configure do |config|
  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

This should help. For more details read [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/foolproof-i18n-setup-in-rails).

---

Also if you just want to find all the missing translations [this gem](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) looks promising. I've personally not used this gem, but seems like an ideal way to find missing translations instead of writing a script by myself:

```
i18n-tasks missing
```

Gem also has a task to find all unused translations.

Comment: this question is not about missing translations, it is about to find hardcoded text to move it to the translation file.